# Antimatter propulsion

Tags: antimatter, rocket-science

I was reading about antimatter propulsion systems on the internet, and apparently they would work by letting matter and antimatter react and then the reaction would be (magnetically) channeled out through a nozzle. So what I was wondering about was that if the matter and antimatter react in a combustion chamber, how would the chamber be designed as to not let the reaction destroy it? Most articles were low on specifics and there was nothing on the internet about how the combustion would work. Am I missing something here or is that a flaw in the design?

Comment: One problem is that you can’t channel the resulting high-energy photons with magnets.

Comment: Ok but is there any other way to convert, let's say, 95% of the reaction (or some other large percentage) to thrust?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know. This seems more engineering than physics, and it takes vast amounts of energy to make antimatter. It's not like we dig it out of mines. So I think the idea is completely unrealistic until we have unlimited amounts of virtually cost-free energy. Antimatter propulsion isn’t something most physicists currently take seriously.

Comment: So it's not physically impossible to be able to channel 95% of the reaction mass to thrust but only problem is that we don't know how? So in the future, it could be possible?

Comment: There is a lot of antimatter made in Earth atmosphere and then trapped by the magnetic field to make part of the van Allen's belt around Earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sources are typically low on specifics because the specifics do not exist i.e., matter/antimatter propulsion is a purely theoretical construct which makes mathematical sense but which cannot be implemented in practice for among other things the issue you cite (what do you make the antimatter storage tank and the "combustion chamber" out of?).

In addition, the only methods currently at hand for manufacturing and then storing antimatter are absurdly inefficient, making a matter/antimatter rocket engine absurdly expensive.

So, you'll read about this in "gee-whiz" science articles and in sci-fi stories, where the specifics "need not concern us".

Comment: So it's not physically impossible to be able to do it but the only problem is that we don't know how? So in the future, it could be possible?

Comment: it is not physically impossible, but  totally impractical.

Comment: There is a lot of antimatter made in outer space, a lot more than in the LHC. So maybe the antimatter in space could be used for propulsion.

Comment: @roghan arun, there is NOT a lot of antimatter in space.

Comment: There is still a little antimatter in space, lot more than can be made in the LHC.

Comment: where is it? what evidence?

Comment: There is a decent amount of antiprotons in the magnetic field of the Earth and probably the Sun's magnetic field, so that can still be a source of energy. There might be hundreds of thousands of antiprotons in the magnetic field, and the antimatter itself doesn't need to be the sole source of energy but can be used to catalyze fusion reactions.

Comment: @MiltonTheMeme antiprotons in the earth's magnetic field??? name your source.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the antimatter is the positron, the only matter particle that needs to be kept away is the electron. So a proton swarm would do. A positron can only annihilate an electron not a proton. The electrons can be added to perform the reaction between the positron and electrons and this can form the propulsion. On top of the proton preventing the positron from hitting the electron in the containers, magnetic traps can hold the positrons in the center of the reaction. If the reaction was sent out through the nozzle propulsion would not be that great, that is because the result of the electron positron annihilation which are gamma rays is not a good propulsion. What needs to happen is on top of the energy leaving the nozzle some of the matter and antimatter also needs to leave the nozzle. However only a small amount of matter and antimatter needs to leave. This can create the required thrust to push on the antimatter spaceship.

Comment: Of course this is what a theoretical ship would need, however there are a lot of details I missed and this sort of propulsion is just not ready at the moment. Also a antiproton proton collision would be more efficient as it creates more energy.

Answer (score 0):

When Matter and Anti-matter interact they annihilate. Virtually all consecutive rest mass is converted to energy with about 2% converted into neutrinos. And there is no combustion.

Scifi series like Star Trek realistically depict antimatter by needing a higher ratio of additional matter introduced as a feedstock as to produce a plasma. If we're to make a plasma style rocket using Antimatter exhausting it's byproducts are high energy photons which are essentially inconsequental mass would be essentially useless. Much like a jet engine a "Afterburner" is needed, in this case a pre-heated plasma of hydrogen gas, an inert gas (Xenon, etc already used in [real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) plasma thrusters), Even water atomized can be used as an exhaust (See Alien Film franchise)

Magnetic containment only works to hold antimatter. The Best strategy to avoid destroying the chamber is avoid a chamber or having a HUGE one. Jet engines use variable diameter thrust nozzles to channel exhaust flow depending on speed, but the idea the chamber acting as a bellows to throw adjacent matter away isn't farfetched The chamber can be channeled magnetically using those grooves, in essence turning reactant chamber into one big nozzle [image]

The best strategy is a ratio of 25:1 matter-antimatter inside a HUGE reaction chamber then exhausting the 24 additional, now highly energized matter.